# Show user (role) specific content

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a site which is going to be used by different schools my company that is working with. A school will have a specific user account and I want to be able to provide school specific content that will only be visible for the logged in school (pdf:s etc).

I've been looking around but haven't found a straightforward solution for this yet (is there even one?). So, what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create a custom role with certain capabilities with the [add_role()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) function and then show content based on the capabilities the current user has with the function [current_user_can()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) you didn't mention if the content will be in the backend or frontend but the principle is the same.

---

**Edit:**

Also this plugin seems to cover what you need [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/)

Comment: Thanks. The content will be frontend. Do you know if there's any plugins for this?